# When PHP uploads excel file to MYSQL duplicate column name error

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have used 2 methods to upload a file to my MYSQL db using PHP at first I only used CSV, and now changed it to upload .xlxs files. what happens is when I try to upload a file and there are 2 matching entries is says duplicate column name and the value of that entry.

For example:

id | open | close

1 | 23 | 23

(I dont know how to format it into a nice table)

this throws the error of duplicate columns names and hence does not INSERT however if I would change the open and close columns to be unique it runs fine. and these specific fields in the table can have unique values.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    // This is the file path to be uploaded.
    $inputFileName = 'discussdesk.xlsx'; 

    try {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet


for($i=$many_many;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
                $barcode = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]));
                $open = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]));
                $close = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["F"]));
                $date = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]));


                $insertTable= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_stock (_date, _barcode, _open, _close) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$date."', '".$barcode."', '".$open."', '".$close."') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT _barcode FROM tbl_stock WHERE _barcode = '".$barcode."' AND _date = '".$date."')");

                if(!$insertTable){die(mysql_error($link));}
}
```

Comment: correct the sql `INSERT INTO tbl_stock (_date, _barcode, _open, _close) VALUES SELECT * FROM` add the keyword `Values`.... try it and let me know, if it works or not

Comment: according to the problem description, isn't it more of a database schema issue? appears to be keys associated with the schema. what's the table schema?

Comment: bhushya, the SQL: INSERT... is correct and does what I need it to do. I  am checking if a date for the specific entry already exists otherwise my data will be one big mess.

Mohammad Aftab Uddin: the schema is utf8_general_ci